# Adding a Radio button of material UI inside row cell in table,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, material-ui

My design currently stands like this[image: Table Design]

I am using Material UI's radio button, i want to make each row select able just once. When i add a `<RadioButton>` component, i am able to select it but however i am not able to toggle between rows

```
  transactionRow(member: Object) {
    return (
      <tr id='drawLotteryTabel' style={styles.tr} key={member.uuid}>
        <td className="col-md-2 col-xs-2">{member.user.fullName}</td>
        <td className="col-md-1 col-xs-1">{this.getSubscriptionDropDown(member.subscriptions)}</td>
        <td className="col-md-2 col-xs-2">{CommonConstants.INR_SYMBOL + ' ' + Utils.formatNumberLocalised(member.bidDiscountAmount || 0)}</td>
        <td className="col-md-2 col-xs-2">{CommonConstants.INR_SYMBOL + ' ' + Utils.formatNumberLocalised(member.bidDiscountPercent || 0)}</td>
        <td className="col-md-2 col-xs-2">{CommonConstants.INR_SYMBOL + ' ' + Utils.formatNumberLocalised(member.unpaidAmount || 0)}</td>
        <td
          className="col-md-2 col-xs-2"
        >
          <RadioButtonGroup name="shipSpeed" defaultSelected="not_light" key={member.uuid}>
            <RadioButton
              value="light"
              style={styles.radioButton}
            />
          </RadioButtonGroup></td>
      </tr>

    );
  }
```

The Above code results in something like this
[image: Result]

What should i do so that i get the entire table row as a single entity to select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably, unfortunately, need to manage the state of your radio buttons manually, as a controlled component.

Have the `RadioButtonGroup` include a call to an `onChange` function that stores the selected value:

```
handleChange: (event, value) => {
    this.setState({selectedButtonValue: value});
}
```

And then push that value to every RadioButtonGroup using the `valueSelected` property as such;

```
<RadioButtonGroup name="shipSpeed" defaultSelected="not_light" key={member.uuid}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    valueSelected={this.state.selectedButtonValue}
>
```

Comment: will this unselect a previously selected row? I think this will set the same value for all the rows

Comment: It will set the same value.  That's what you want.  Though I now also see that your "value" is hard coded, where it should be a dynamic property linked to the row.  Try using the `member.uuid` as the value for the RadioButton as well.

Comment: That was just for the sake of the qn.. editing that.. Anyway ill try your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using "Enhanced Table" from material ui.
If that's the case

replace

```js
    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, name);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1),
      );
    }
```

with

```js
    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = [name];
    }
```

and replace

The Checkbox component with Radio component.

change this

```js
<TableCell padding="checkbox">
    <Checkbox
     checked={isItemSelected}
     inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': labelId }}
     />
 </TableCell>
```

to this

```js
<TableCell padding="checkbox">
     <Radio
      checked={isItemSelected}
      inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': labelId }}
      />
</TableCell>
```

You should be able to toggle between the radio buttons as the button only activates when new row is selected and it replaces the old selected state.

I am attaching the implementation of material ui enhanced table with radio button implementation. I did some tweak here and there. You can take a look.

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { lighten, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TablePagination from '@material-ui/core/TablePagination';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import TableSortLabel from '@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
// import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
// import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
// import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
// import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
// import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
// import FilterListIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FilterList';

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData('Donut', 452, 25.0, 51, 4.9),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData('Honeycomb', 408, 3.2, 87, 6.5),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData('Jelly Bean', 375, 0.0, 94, 0.0),
  createData('KitKat', 518, 26.0, 65, 7.0),
  createData('Lollipop', 392, 0.2, 98, 0.0),
  createData('Marshmallow', 318, 0, 81, 2.0),
  createData('Nougat', 360, 19.0, 9, 37.0),
  createData('Oreo', 437, 18.0, 63, 4.0),
];

function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
  if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
  return order === 'desc'
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}

function stableSort(array, comparator) {
  const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
  stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
    const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
    if (order !== 0) return order;
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });
  return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
}

const headCells = [
  { id: 'name', numeric: false, disablePadding: true, label: 'Dessert (100g serving)' },
  { id: 'calories', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Calories' },
  { id: 'fat', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Fat (g)' },
  { id: 'carbs', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Carbs (g)' },
  { id: 'protein', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Protein (g)' },
];

function EnhancedTableHead(props) {
  const { classes, order, orderBy, onRequestSort } = props;
  const createSortHandler = (property) => (event) => {
    onRequestSort(event, property);
  };

  return (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell padding="checkbox">
        </TableCell>
        {headCells.map((headCell) => (
          <TableCell
            key={headCell.id}
            align={headCell.numeric ? 'right' : 'left'}
            padding={headCell.disablePadding ? 'none' : 'default'}
            sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
          >
            <TableSortLabel
              active={orderBy === headCell.id}
              direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : 'asc'}
              onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
            >
              {headCell.label}
              {orderBy === headCell.id ? (
                <span className={classes.visuallyHidden}>
                  {order === 'desc' ? 'sorted descending' : 'sorted ascending'}
                </span>
              ) : null}
            </TableSortLabel>
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  );
}

EnhancedTableHead.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  onRequestSort: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onSelectAllClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  order: PropTypes.oneOf(['asc', 'desc']).isRequired,
  orderBy: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  rowCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

const useToolbarStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(2),
    paddingRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  highlight:
    theme.palette.type === 'light'
      ? {
          color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
          backgroundColor: lighten(theme.palette.secondary.light, 0.85),
        }
      : {
          color: theme.palette.text.primary,
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.dark,
        },
  title: {
    flex: '1 1 100%',
  },
}));

const EnhancedTableToolbar = (props) => {
  const classes = useToolbarStyles();
  const { numSelected } = props;

  return (
    <Toolbar
      className={clsx(classes.root, {
        [classes.highlight]: numSelected.length > 0,
      })}
    >
      {numSelected.length > 0 ? (
        <Typography className={classes.title} color="inherit" variant="subtitle1" component="div">
          {numSelected}
        </Typography>
      ) : (
        <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" id="tableTitle" component="div">
          Nutrition
        </Typography>
      )}

      {/* {numSelected.length > 0 ? (
        <Tooltip title="Delete">
          <IconButton aria-label="delete">
            <DeleteIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      ) : (
        <Tooltip title="Filter list">
          <IconButton aria-label="filter list">
            <FilterListIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      )} */}
    </Toolbar>
  );
};

EnhancedTableToolbar.propTypes = {
  numSelected: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  paper: {
    width: '100%',
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 750,
  },
  visuallyHidden: {
    border: 0,
    clip: 'rect(0 0 0 0)',
    height: 1,
    margin: -1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    padding: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 20,
    width: 1,
  },
}));

export default function EnhancedTableWithRadio() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [order, setOrder] = React.useState('asc');
  const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = React.useState('calories');
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState('');
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  // const [dense, setDense] = React.useState(false);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);

  const handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
    const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === 'asc';
    setOrder(isAsc ? 'desc' : 'asc');
    setOrderBy(property);
  };


  const handleClick = (event, name) => {
    let newSelected = selected;

    if (name !== selected) {
      newSelected = name;
    }
    setSelected(newSelected);
  };

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
    setPage(0);
  };

  // const handleChangeDense = (event) => {
  //   setDense(event.target.checked);
  // };

  const isSelected = (name) => selected.indexOf(name) !== -1;

  const emptyRows = rowsPerPage - Math.min(rowsPerPage, rows.length - page * rowsPerPage);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
      <EnhancedTableToolbar numSelected={selected} />
        <TableContainer>
          <Table
            className={classes.table}
            aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
            // size={dense ? 'small' : 'medium'}
            size = "medium"
            aria-label="enhanced table"
          >
            <EnhancedTableHead
              classes={classes}
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={rows.length}
            />
            <TableBody>
              {stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map((row, index) => {
                  const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.name);
                  const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      hover
                      onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.name)}
                      role="checkbox"
                      aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                      tabIndex={-1}
                      key={row.name}
                      selected={isItemSelected}
                    >
                      <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                        <Radio
                          checked={isItemSelected}
                          inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': labelId }}
                        />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" id={labelId} scope="row" padding="none">
                        {row.name}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
              {emptyRows > 0 && (
                <TableRow style={{ height: 53 * emptyRows }}>
                {/* <TableRow style={{ height: (dense ? 33 : 53) * emptyRows }}> */}
                
                  <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        <TablePagination
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10]}
          component="div"
          count={rows.length}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          page={page}
          onChangePage={handleChangePage}
          onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
      </Paper>
      {/* <FormControlLabel
        control={<Switch checked={dense} onChange={handleChangeDense} />}
        label="Dense padding"
      /> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using a Radio button component inside a cell from a Table, both components from MaterialUi.  I resolve like this:

This is my handleChange function to select de value of the Row.id that i use for my app

```
handleChange(field, event) {
        this.setState({[field] : event.target.value});
    }
```

And in my Table component i just use the "Radio" component without a "RadioButtonGoup" component. And use a condition in the "checked" prop of the "Radio" component to show it as checked or not.

```
<Table aria-label="simple table">
   <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
         <TableCell align="center">Selecciona</TableCell>
         <TableCell>Brand</TableCell>
         <TableCell align="center">Tarjetahabiente</TableCell>
         <TableCell align="center">Terminación</TableCell>
         <TableCell align="center">Expira</TableCell>
         <TableCell align="center">Eliminar</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
   </TableHead>
   <TableBody>
      {rows.map(row => (
      <TableRow key={row.id}>
         <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
            <Radio
               value={row.id}
               defaultSelected={false}
               checked={row.id != this.state.paymentSourceId ? false : true}
               onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'paymentSourceId')}
            />
         </TableCell>
         <TableCell align="center">{row.brand}</TableCell>
         <TableCell align="center">{row.name}</TableCell>
         <TableCell align="center">{row.last4}</TableCell>
         <TableCell align="center">{row.exp_month}/{row.exp_year}</TableCell>
         <TableCell align="center">
             <IconButton 
                 aria-label="delete" 
                 color="primary" 
                 onClick={()=>this.handleDelete(this.state.paymentSourceId)}>
                   <DeleteIcon />
              </IconButton>
         </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      ))}
   </TableBody>
</Table>
```